# Want to execute url with Port number

Tags: php

Dear all please help me how can i execute following url using cURL using php?

https://telenorcsms.com.pk:27677/corporate_sms2/api/auth.jsp?msisdn=923468211085&password=Javed1212

i am tring this but no result found.

```
$tuCurl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://telenorcsms.com.pk/corporate_sms2/api/auth.jsp?msisdn=923468211085&password=Javed1212"); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_PORT , 27677); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); // 5 seconds timeout

$tuData = curl_exec($tuCurl); 
curl_close($tuCurl);

echo $tuData;
```

Comment: theres an SSL setting for curl. You might want to play with that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your request is at the "middle" of authentication process. 
Perhaps, you need to consider some credentials over the request to access the needed resource.
At first, set `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` in active mode : `true(1)` (to obtain the details of the request processing).
Secondly, that site returns an `XML` response back. 
Use `var_dump` to get more details about response.
Here is how it looks now:

```
$tuCurl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://telenorcsms.com.pk/corporate_sms2/api/auth.jsp?msisdn=923468211085&password=Javed1212"); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_PORT , 27677); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); // 5 seconds timeout

$tuData = curl_exec($tuCurl); 
curl_close($tuCurl);

var_dump($tuData);
```

The output:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>








  <corpsms>
    <command>Auth_request</command>
    <data>8c22d08be9bd492ea06bef31af4d62f3</data>
    <response>OK</response>
  </corpsms >

'
```